# Gnucash checkbook columns shrunk too far. Cannot get them back!

Tags: gnucash

I'm working in my checkbook register in gnucash.

The column headings are in green, with black vertical lines separating them.

The black vertical lines between

1. Date and Num,
2. Num and Description, and
3. Description and Transfer

are all normal width.

The line between Transfer and Deposit is darker. I think the 'Reconcile' column is hiding in there.

The line between Deposit and Balance is actually two lines. The Withdrawal column is hiding between them, I'm pretty sure.

No matter how I drag the lines around, I can't get the Withdrawal and Reconcile  columns to be displayed again. I closed the register and reopened it.

I closed the app and reopened it.

I double clicked Balance. No help there.

I'm going to try to change my screen resolution.

I'm on Windows 11.

How do I get the columns to reappear again?

Thank you.

Comment: This is probably more suitable for superuser.com, as it is about software usage, not finance.

Comment: @chepner Questions about the usage of personal finance software are on-topic.  See [Should questions on the technical usage of a financial management tool be on-topic, or off-topic?](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/127/10997)

Comment: I found the answer in the GnuCash Wiki FAQ.  The question is: How do I resize my register columns?  ANSWER: It can be difficult to recover if you reduce a column to invisibility. In that case if you're unable to grab its right edge because you keep getting the next column's edge instead, you can recover it as follows:
    Quit GnuCash and open GNC_DATA_DIR/books/your-book-name.gnucash.gcm in a text editor.   It explains what to edit in the .gcm file.

Comment: @L-gnucash I'm glad you found your answer.  Please post the answer you found as an answer to this question by entering it in the "Your Answer" box below.

Answer (score 7):

This is quoted from the GnuCash wiki FAQ: https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/FAQ#Q:_How_do_I_resize_my_register_columns.3F_Why_can_I_not_shrink_the_description_column.3F

> Q: How do I resize my register columns? Why can I not shrink the description column?

> It can be difficult to recover if you reduce a column to invisibility. In that case if you're unable to grab its right edge because you keep getting the next column's edge instead, you can recover it as follows: Quit GnuCash and open GNC_DATA_DIR/books/your-book-name.gnucash.gcm in a text editor. It contains blocks describing each register you've ever had open with a heading that looks something like

```
[Register 8305149bc462f9b5d118c259df706e7b]
```

> Don't worry about the number, just look through all of them for an entry like (balance is an example, if you shrunk a different column look for its name)

```
balance_width=0
```

> It might be some other low number like 1 or 2. Change it to a bigger number, e.g.

```
balance_width=85
```

> Save the file and restart GnuCash.

Comment: I have had this GnuCash behaviour in other accounts too, so I like your question and answer. Maybe more veteran users can confirm whether this applies to "normal" accounts or not. I just took a deep breath and "minimized" some column in GnuCash 4.9 but I managed with my mouse to pull the divider to the right again. So not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The Wiki tells you to drag the balance right edge out past the window but that does not work for me, the GUI is not letting me grab and resize the Balance column on the right.  What does work is to double-click on the balance column header to auto-size it.